# Nested virtualization on a macOS host

Tags: macos, mac, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm currently running a Linux VM on my Mac using VirtualBox. I'd like to set up another nested VM inside my Linux VM, also using VirtualBox. However, the option to `Enable Nested VT-x /AMD-V` is greyed out. What's happening?

[image]

Comment: What is your Mac and which macOS is installed on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox does not support nested virtualization on macOS 13+; [VirtualBox relied on a type of kext that's no longer supported on later versions of macOS](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=108062) for nested virtualization. Apple now requires that hypervisors use their virtualization framework.

You can either use [VMware Fusion, which definitely supports it](https://graspingtech.com/nested-virtualization-mac/), or QEMU/[UTM](https://mac.getutm.app), which may or may not work.

Keep in mind that nested virtualization is *not* supported by Apple Silicon chips; you'll need an x86 chip to use nested virtualization.

Comment: Thank you so much, the nested virtualization is run with VMware Fusion when I check on hypervisor.